# Constructor not defined: [CircularProgressController].<Constructor>(Case, Id, Decimal, Decimal) (Line: 15, Column: 45)

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am trying to finish up this test class, with the issue listed above. The Class I am testing is as follows:

```
public with sharing class CircularProgressController {    

    /**
     * This class is used to return as JSON Object
     **/
    class WrapperJSON{
        public Integer total {get;set;}
        public Integer actual {get;set;}
        public Integer val {get;set;}
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String computePercentage(String sObjectName, String recordId, String totalValueFieldName, String actualValueFieldName){
        Integer retVal = 0 ;
        String query = null;
        WrapperJSON retObj = new WrapperJSON();

        if(totalValueFieldName != null && totalValueFieldName.trim() != '' &&  actualValueFieldName != null && actualValueFieldName.trim() != '' ){
            query = 'SELECT '+totalValueFieldName+', '+actualValueFieldName+' FROM '+sObjectName+' WHERE Id =: recordId';
        }
        else if (actualValueFieldName != null && actualValueFieldName.trim() != '' ) {
            query = 'SELECT '+actualValueFieldName+' FROM '+sObjectName+' WHERE Id =: recordId';
        }

        if(query != null){
            try{
                List<SOBject> lstObj = Database.query(query);
                if(lstObj.size() > 0){
                    Decimal totalVal = 0;
                    Decimal actualVal = 0; 

                    if(totalValueFieldName != null && totalValueFieldName.trim() != ''){ 
                        totalVal = Decimal.valueOf(String.valueOf(lstObj[0].get(totalValueFieldName)));
                        retObj.total = Integer.valueOf(totalVal) ; 
                    } 
                    actualVal = Decimal.valueOf(String.valueOf(lstObj[0].get(actualValueFieldName)));                     
                    //Means only 1 API Name was supplied and field type is percentage
                    if(totalVal == 0){
                        retObj.val = Integer.valueOf(actualVal) ; 
                        retObj.actual = Integer.valueOf(actualVal) ;  
                    }else if (actualVal > 0){
                        retObj.val = Integer.valueOf( ( actualVal / totalVal ) * 100 );   
                        retObj.actual = Integer.valueOf(actualVal) ;  
                    } 
                }
            }catch(Exception e){}

        }         
        return JSON.serialize(retObj) ;        
    }
}
```

The test class I have is

```
   @IsTest
public class circularProgressControllerTest {

private static testMethod void runTest()
{
    Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Account Test', Type = 'Customer');
    insert acc;
    Case a = new Case(Subject = 'Account Tester', Status='New', Origin='Email', AccountId = acc.Id);
    insert a;

     a = [select id, Status from Case where id =:a.Id];
     a.Status = 'Open';
        update a;
     a = [select id, First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c, SLA_HI__c from Case where id =:a.Id];
    CircularProgressController JsonString = new CircularProgressController(a, a.Id, a.SLA_HI__c, a.First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c);
    //String JsonString = CircularProgressController.computePercentage();

    Map<String, Object> meta = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(JsonString);
    List<Map<String, String>> myMaps = (List<Map<String, String>>) meta.get('results');

   Test.startTest();

   System.assertNotEquals(null, myMaps.Val);

   Test.stopTest();


    }

}
```

And again, the error I am receiving is `Result: [OPERATION FAILED]: classes/CircularProgressControllerTest.cls: Constructor not defined: [CircularProgressController].<Constructor>(Case, Id, Decimal, Decimal) (Line: 15, Column: 45)`

Answer (score 2):

You have not defined any constructors, so only the implicit 0-argument constructor is callable. You can then pass these arguments into your `computePercentage` method:

```
MyController controller = new MyController();
controller.myMethod(/*params*/);
```

You still have to pass the correct parameters, however. You've got the first two right, but then you've only got one more and it's not the right type. You need to pass string. So if you want to pass the field name `First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c`, it would look something like:

```
controller.myMethod(a, a.Id, 'First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c', 'Second_Field__c');
```

Comment: I've [moved this conversation to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58621/discussion-on-answer-by-adrian-larson-constructor-not-defined-circularprogress).